# Kubernetes https service exposure

Tags: https, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I currently have a Google Kubernetes load balancer service with an external endpoint over http/port 80. How can I expose this service on a secure endpoint over https/port 443. For my application’s purposes, I need to be able to use an https URL. I have read some documentation about ingress etc but it hasn’t particularly made sense to me. I was hoping someone could please specifically explain how to go about changing my http endpoint to an https endpoint? Do I need to get an SSL certificate? Make any modifications to the YAML of my Kubernetes cluster or can I achieve this simply through the GUI/GCP console?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use open certificate using lets-encrypt. With using kube-lego and ingress-nginx controller you can easily add https to your service. If you agreed in this stack, I can give you an example.

Comment: I’d really appreciate an examples thanks!

Comment: Sorry for late reply, do you use helm?

Comment: I haven't used it before.

Comment: Did you find an easy solution for this?

Comment: Due to my lack of familiarity with Kubernetes I decided to use Google Compute Engine in the meantime, so no sorry I don't.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs) view on GCP:

> In Google Kubernetes Engine, you can use Ingresses to create HTTPS load balancers with automatically configured SSL certificates.

**Important**

The product is still in [Beta](https://cloud.google.com/products/#product-launch-stages), which means it's not yet totally recommended for production, but I've set it up for a couple of clusters now and it seems to be working fine.